# nodejs domain based routing

Tags: node.js

I have server with single IP address. I have 3 nodejs services. Each service has its own domain. f.e.

- a.company.com,
- b.company.com,
- c.company.com

They written by different people so integration into single application problematic.
My aim is to make nodejs routing of different requests to these different services based on hostname mentioned in GET/POST request.
I know that I can use NGINX for such kind of routing but I'm sure it will slowdown whole solution. I still plan to keep speed of 2K Req/s. So I prefer to stay in nice Async world of nodejs.

Any advices?

Thanks

Comment: why not put something like nginx in front?

Comment: It slow down according to my tests in 2 times whole service.

Comment: nginx is programmed using asynchronous io and propably the fastest webserver in the world currently. Ryan Dahl, the creator of node, always references nginx as what he is aiming at performance wise. No matter which reverse proxy solution you will implement (and you will require one given your circumstances) you will loose performance due to reverse proxying.

Comment: Try to use [Clusterjs](http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/).

Comment: Adding in some sort of routing based on domain name is always going to add time to execution.  That said, I think the recommendations of a properly configured nginx will serve you best.  It's fast, tested, and reliable.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using connect, there's the [connect.vhost](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html) middleware. The repo itself has [an example of using connect.vhost for subdomains](https://github.com/expressjs/vhost). The example could be adapted to using different domains just by changing the host names (for example it could be `foo.com` and `bar.com` like it is on the example in the first link in this post).

If you want your domains in separate processes, I recommend using [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). Or, you could use [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) to divide up some work between processes but still have the one process handle all of the HTTP. It's a good idea to move things that are likely to use up lots of memory or crash in separate processes, so they don't bring the whole server down.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using nodejs TCP-proxy to do this. All explanations are in code.

```js
var net = require('net');

// your hosts
var dns = {
  'localhost' : 8000,
  'b.host' : 3000,
  'a.host' : 3001
};

// Create TCP-server
var server = net.createServer( function(soc){ // soc is socket generated by net.Server

  // Incoming request processing
  soc.on('data', function(data){


    // Create new socket
    var client = net.Socket();

    // Get host from HTTP headers
    var re = /[^\n]+(\r\n|\r|\n)host:\w*([^:]+)/i;
    var host = data.toString('utf-8').match(re);

    if (! dns[host])
    {
      soc.end('HTTP/1.1 404 Host not found');
      return;
    }

    // Connect to Node.js application
    client.connect(dns[host]);

    // Pause soc for inner socket connection
    soc.pause();

    client.on('connect', function()
    {
      // Write request to your node.js application
      client.write(data.toString('utf-8'));
    });

    client.on('data', function(cdata)
    {
      // Return socket to live
      soc.resume();

      // Write client data to browser
      soc.write(cdata.toString('utf-8'));
      soc.pipe(soc);
      soc.end();
    });

    client.on('end', function(){
      client.destroy();
    });
  });
}
);

server.on('error', function (err){
  // Error processing i just pass whole object
  console.log(err);
});

server.listen(8088);
console.log('Server is listening %d\n', 8088);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nginx or node-http-proxy

http://blog.nodejitsu.com/http-proxy-middlewares
http://blog.nodejitsu.com/http-proxy-intro